# Minix 3.2.1 Modifying do_mkdir to print the absolute file path

Tags: minix

I want to modify do_mkdir in /usr/src/servers/vfs/open.c in order to when i try to use mkdir command to print in terminal the absolute path to the directory i created.How can i achive that ? Any ideas?

I tried the getcwd but i got a undefined reference error .

Answer (score 0):

The full path is in the variable fullpath defined in the beginning of the `do_mkdir` function. Also the access rights are on the variables listed in the code below

```
printf("New dir -> %s, ", fullpath);
printf( (bits & S_IRUSR) ? "r" : "-");
printf( (bits & S_IWUSR) ? "w" : "-");
printf( (bits & S_IXUSR) ? "x" : "-");
printf( (bits & S_IRGRP) ? "r" : "-");
printf( (bits & S_IWGRP) ? "w" : "-");
printf( (bits & S_IXGRP) ? "x" : "-");
printf( (bits & S_IROTH) ? "r" : "-");
printf( (bits & S_IWOTH) ? "w" : "-");
printf( (bits & S_IXOTH) ? "x\n" : "-\n");
```

Put this code in the end of the `do_mkdir` just before the   `unlock_vnode(vp);` line and you are done!

Έχεις κάνει τα υπόλοιπα ερωτήματα??

Comment: Στο 3ο ειμαι εδω και 2 μερες :p ...Δεν παλευονται

Answer (score 0):

I believe that simply printing the fullpath variable doesn't work.
Actually, I tested this out and it seems to print only the name of the directory created. Any clues?

Comment: I agree with you I also tested this and it seems to print only the name of the new directory